# response.sendRedirect attempts to redirect multiple times by server

Tags: jquery, servlets, double-redirect

`sendRedirect` in some java servlet and this servlet is referred in jquery ajax. When server encounters-307(redirect) the redirection request comes repeatedly to browser after every 15 seconds. Following log illustrates this

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcNO6.png)

What might be the possible reason? Is there any configuration or behavior that browsers or server can reattempt redirects repeatedly?

Comment: Can you post some code?  What exactly is happening?

Comment: looks your ajax is calling this servlet in 15sec intervals...

Comment: I think you need to redirect the page via javascript when it's 307 and not 200

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a *double redirect* problem.

One page on load is used to redirect to another action. Then another action is redirected back to the previous page.

To prevent this kind of error you should change the code because under some conditions, the first page won't redirect automatically, or the second action won't redirect to the page which redirects to the second action again.

Here to learn more about [Double redirects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Double_redirects) .